# Firebase Authentication and Django/Djangae

Tags: python, django, firebase-authentication

I am evaluating if Firebase authentication to see if it works well with Django/Djangae. Here comes some context

1. require email/password authentication, able to additional field like job title, and basic things like reset password email.
2. use Djanage framework (Django that uses datastore as data storage), app engine.
3. really good to make use built-in authentication tool provided by Django, like session, require-loggin, etc.

Drop-in authentication seems to be a candidate. Does it work with Django authentication, like permission, group, etc.

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase authentication only supports login/signup, reset password or email.
but for that you need firebase admin credentials.

For other field you need local model. There is no problem with using django, but also no existing integration I'm aware of, so you'd have to hook it up yourself.

if you want auth-system like firebase and other functionality than you can use social-django-restframework. you can integrate all login system with your django app and control user with inbuilt user model.